# Date wrong increasing in Java for Android

Tags: java, android, date

I am trying to build a calendar app in Android Studio. Everything works fine despite one little thing. When I have a repeating event (lets say weekly), and after inserting it - which works fine - and I tried to increase it with the function:

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);
```

The following happens:
It inserts events exactly to the end of the month and in the next year in the same month again, so how can I achieve, that also the month increases and the event will appear next month?

Hope I could explain what I mean.

Comment: Consider sharing your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a week (7 days) in your calendar, you should use `Calendar.DATE` and not `Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance()
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
```

Comment: I've used this code before, and im 1000% sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Joda-Time

Alternatively you could use the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. The old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome and should be avoided.

If you want only date without time-of-day, use the [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(); // Gets today's date using JVM’s current default time zone. You may want to specify a time zone instead, passing a `DateTimeZone` object.
LocalDate weekLater = today.plusWeeks( 1 );
```

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes bundled with the new [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. Inspired by Joda-Time, defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. Intended to be the successor to Joda-Time. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Java 8 technology is not currently available in Android. But there have been some back-port projects. I've heard the back-port may work well in Android but I do not know details.

Comment: I would prefer a solution without external libraries but if there is no other solution i'll try that

Comment: @JulCode The old date-time classes really are so bad that adding Joda-Time is the first thing I do when setting up any new Java project.